# Is there a browser-based client-side version of freighter-api?

Tags: stellar-core

Is there a browser-based client-side version of freighter-api, so it can be used without installing on the server?

For example, web3.min_1.36.js can be used as a script tag in an HTML file that is run from the local machine.